# PHP foreach $output variation?

Tags: php

I need a little help on getting a rule in to output something else if a certain variable is called.
To break it down I have the following listed:

```
private $zebra_moto_symbol = array
( "ES400", "MC9500", "MC9200", "MC9190", "MC9094", "MC9090", "MC9097", "MC9060",;
```

and using this code it pulls the models into the page in a list:

```
public function manufacturer_models_list() { 
    $manu_name = $this->manufacturer_name; 
    $output = "<ul>"; 

    sort($this->$manu_name); 
    foreach($this->$manu_name as $model) { 
        $output .= "<li>" . "<a href=\"repair.php\">" . $model . "</a></li>"; 
    } 

    $output .= "</ul>"; 
    $output .= "<p class=\"clear\"></p>"; 
    $output .= "<a href=\"repair.php\" " . "id=\"arrange-repair\">Arrange A Repair</a>"; 
    return $output; 
}
```

On all but two of these, I need it display the repair.php link, however on two these need to be different. What would I need to input to make this happen?
Thanks in advance (sorry, this one stumped me).
:)

Comment: Can you format your code please (if possible) In its current form it is a little hard to read.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Take your time to explore the site and the functionalities of the question editor. There is nice `{}` button that can be used to mark a block of text as code. Also, don't put all the code on a single line as it is hard to read. Under the editor there is a preview of your question to know how it looks like and make the adjustments before submitting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `switch` statement for this.

```
<?
    public function manufacturer_models_list() {
        $manu_name = $this->manufacturer_name;
        $output    = "<ul>";
        sort($this->$manu_name);
        foreach ($this->$manu_name as $model) {
            switch($model) {
                //Output NOT repair.php on this list of strings
                case "ES400":
                case "MC9500":
                    $output .= "<li>DIFFERENT OUTPUT</a></li>";
                    break;
                //default is the action that happens if none of the previous conditions are met
                default:
                    $output .= "<li>" . "<a href=\"repair.php\">" . $model . "</a></li>";
                    break;
            }
        }
        $output .= "</ul>";
        $output .= "<p class=\"clear\"></p>";
        $output .= "<a href=\"repair.php\" " . "id=\"arrange-repair\">Arrange A Repair</a>";
        return $output;
    }
?>
```

Read more about [Switch Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, what you want is to have a different output on certain values.

I would think about have another array to hold the values that you want a different output and you can do something like this:

```
$different_output_array = ['ES400', 'MC9500']; # you can add new elements any time
```

and just modify your function to something like this:

```
public function manufacturer_models_list() { 
    $manu_name = $this->manufacturer_name; 
    $output = "<ul>"; 

    sort($this->$manu_name); 
    foreach($this->$manu_name as $model) { 

        if(in_array($model,$different_output_array))
        {
            $output .= "<li>" . "<a href=\"another.php\">" . $model . "</a></li>"; 
        }
        else
        {
            $output .= "<li>" . "<a href=\"repair.php\">" . $model . "</a></li>"; 
        }


    } 

    $output .= "</ul>"; 
    $output .= "<p class=\"clear\"></p>"; 
    $output .= "<a href=\"repair.php\" " . "id=\"arrange-repair\">Arrange A Repair</a>"; 
    return $output; 
}
```

Hope this can help.